# Using PowerShell to replace string that contains $ in the string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell do a simple find and replace. I use template text files and use `$` in front of values that need to be changed.

Example:

```
(Get-Content "D:\test") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`$TBQUAL", "DBO"} | Set-Content "D:\test"
```

It should find the line `OWNER=$TBQUAL` and make it look like `OWNER=DBO`.

I am using the escape in front of `$TBQUAL` with no luck. To test that it is working if I removed the `$` from the front, it would replace `TBQUAL` and made it look like `OWNER=$DBO`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to get this to work:

1. Use single quotes for your strings so that the `$` is not interpreted as the start of a variable to be expanded.
2. Escape the `$` using a backslash "\" so the regular expression parser takes it literally.

For example,

```
PS C:\> 'Has a $sign in it' -replace 'a \$sign', 'no dollar sign'
Has no dollar sign in it
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in your replacement, you can do a simple (and fast) replace like this:

```
Foreach-Object {$_.Replace('$TBQUAL', 'DBO')}
```